# How much vertical space is used by maketitle?

Tags: spacing

Is it possible to know which portion of `\textheight` has been consumed by (or is remaining after) a `\maketitle` command? I mean considering the applied maketitle (with or without authors, with or without date, ...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{This is a title}
\author{My name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The vertical available space in this page is ...
\end{document}
```

*Update:*

If it's possible I would like a solution also valid for `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{This is a title}
\author{My name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


The used space in this page is
\the\pagetotal\
plus
\ifdim\pagefillstretch=0pt
\ifdim\pagefilstretch=0pt
\the\pagestretch
\else 
\the\pagefillstretch fil
\fi
\else 
\the\pagefillstretch fill
\fi\
minus
\the\pageshrink\
out of \the\pagegoal


\end{document}
```

Comment: This works more generally; one thing to watch out for in the general case (does not apply in this instance because `\maketitle` presumably always occupies nonzero area) is that `\pagegoal` is `\maxdimen` (I think) at the very top of the page. The solution in that case is to take the minimum of `\pagegoal` and `\vsize`, say.

Comment: I'm sorry because I didn't comment it in my original question but this solution doesn't work for `[twocolumn]article`. Is is possible to adapt it?

Comment: @Ignasi not easily, use werner's version in that case (in two column the title has already been boxed and measured and the pagegoal adjusted for the required column heights on that  so you could get the values (actually essentially `\pagegoal` is  all you need than as that's the target height for the column under the title) but it's a completely different calculation.

Answer (score 7):

You can place coordinate markers (similar to `\label`s) on the page and calculate the difference/distance between them. [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module provides `\zsaveposy{<label>}` to mark a vertical position (in `s`caled `p`oints, measured from the bottom of the page, on the baseline of the current line) and `\zposy{<label>}` to retrieve that as part of a calculation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-savepos,eso-pic}

\title{This is a title}
\author{My name}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
  \AtTextUpperLeft{\zsaveposy{text-upper}}%
  \AtTextLowerLeft{\zsaveposy{text-lower}}%
}

\maketitle

\leavevmode\zsaveposy{title}%
Text block lower/upper y-coordinate: \zposy{text-lower}sp/\zposy{text-upper}sp

Current location: \zsaveposy{curpos}\zposy{curpos}sp
(\the\dimexpr\zposy{text-upper}sp-\zposy{curpos}sp\relax/\the\dimexpr\zposy{curpos}sp-\zposy{text-lower}sp\relax{} to top/bottom)

Space used by title: \the\dimexpr\zposy{text-upper}sp-\zposy{title}sp-\baselineskip\relax

\end{document}
```

I use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to place markers at the bottom/top of the text block in order to have a frame of reference.

Since the process uses a `\label`-`\ref`-like setup, at least two compilations are required after any change in the `\zsaveposy` locations.

Answer (score 3):

You can measure the size with `\setbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{This is a title}
\author{My name}

\begin{document}
\setbox0\vbox{\maketitle}

The vertical available space in this page is ...
\expandafter\the\dimexpr\textheight-\ht0\relax
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can but the boxing may change the values....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's correct.